# VBA Dynamic name Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small/complex problem, but I cannot understand why I'm obtaining this error.

In a vba code I have this:

```
ws = Sheets("Calendar") 
c = "Fixed"   
first = ce.Address
end = ce2.Address    
wb.Names.Add Name:=c, RefersTo:=ws.Name & "!" & first & ":" & end
```

The formula create a named range like this one:

```
="Calendar!$M$2:$M$4"
```

This named range doesn't show any values, but if I change manually the named range in this:

```
=Calendar!$M$2:$M$4
```

It will work.

Where is the issue? Why the formula doesn't work? Which parameter is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Multiple issues with your code. `ws = Sheets("Calendar") ` should be `Set ws = Sheets("Calendar") ` and `end` cannot be a variable name.  But the main issue is that the string for `RefersTo:=` must begin with an equal sign. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834743.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. end is not a good variable name
2. ws is an object, so Set should be used to assign it
3. The formula needs a "=" in front of it

`Set ws = Sheets("Calendar")
    c = "Fixed"
    first = ce.Address
    end1 = ce2.Address
    wb.Names.Add Name:=c, RefersTo:="=" & ws.Name & "!" & first & ":" & end1`

Comment: I have translated "first" and "end" without thinking about it. In the original code the name was different. The missing "=" was the problem. Thank you!